# expression which evaluates to $1$ if a number is divisible by $n$ else $-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find a simple algebraic expression in terms of $n$ and $m$ which evaluates to $+1$ if $n$ is divisible by $m$ else $-1$

Specifically I would like to have an expression for the divisibility by $10$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

How about $$1-2\left\lceil\frac{n}{m}-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor\right\rceil$$
Alternatively, using the same idea but allowing $\{x\}$ to denote the fractional part of $x$:
$$1-2\left\lceil\left\{\frac{n}{m}\right\}\right\rceil$$

Comment: This is nice but I have to use the expression in a recursive function. Can this be done using a polynomial in $x$ and $y$??

Comment: @mathsismagic I'm afraid I don't quite understand - I'm not sure what sort of polynomial you would be looking for. On the other hand, if you want this for a computer science application it seems like just using the mod function is easiest: $$f(n)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }n\equiv 0\pmod{m}\\-1&\text{if }n\not\equiv 0\pmod{m}\end{cases}$$